# How to display output as symbols?

Tags: functions, matrix, syntax, symbolic

I have this piece of code which populates a matrix following different rules depending on row and column number:

```
MQp := Array[Qp, {Length[a], Length[a]}];
Do[Qp[i, 1] = a[[i]], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
Do[Qp[1, j] = a[[j]]/2, {j, 2, Length[a]}];
Do[If[(i == j), 
   If[((2 j - 1) <= Length[a]), Qp[i, j] = a[[2 i - 1]]/2 + a[[1]], 
    Qp[i, j] = a[[1]]], 
   If[(i != 1 && j != 1), 
    If[(i + j - 1) <= Length[a], 
     Qp[i, j] = a[[i + j - 1]]/2 + a[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]/2, 
     Qp[i, j] = a[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]/2]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}, {j, 1, 
   Length[a]}];
Qp[1, 1] = a[[1]];
MatrixForm[MQp]
```

Currently "a" is a table of numerical values. I would like to generate a table of symbolic a's, and then be able to substitute the numerical values into the matrix. This way I can easily check that the values in the matrix correctly match what should be generated. I've tried several methods, but so far I get errors or nothing is output at all?
Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

PS: How do I display code blocks correctly? I did a line and eight spaces but it looks like it didn't work.

Comment: You can display the code block by highlighting the code and pressing the button labeled {} in the editor. I just fixed it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate an array of symbolic values using `Array`

```
Clear[a];
a = Array[A, 5];
```

Then your matrix `MQp` becomes:

[image]

You can then check for specific values using a pattern. For example,

```
MQp /. {A[2] -> 3}
```

gives the matrix with 3 in place of `A[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is another way to define your matrix using `SparseArray[]`. Perhaps it's easier to understand:

```
a = Array[A, 5];
b = SparseArray[{
   {i_, 1} :> a[[i]],
   {1, j_} :> a[[j]]/2,
   {i_, i_} /; (2 i - 1) <= Length@a :> a[[2 i - 1]]/2 + a[[1]],
   {i_, i_} /; (2 i - 1) >  Length@a :> a[[1]],
   {i_, j_} /; (i + j - 1) <= Length[a] :> a[[i + j - 1]]/2 + a[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]/2,
   {i_, j_} /; (i + j - 1) >  Length[a] :> a[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]/2},
  Length@a {1, 1}]
b // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]